# TypeError while trying to perform a binary search in python

Tags: python, binary, syntax-error, typeerror

I'm trying to write a binary search and can't get it to work. The array is predetermined and the value the program is searching for needs to be an input. What I have so far is:

```
MYVALUE = input
ARRAY = ["3", "5", "2", "9", "1"]
MAX = len(ARRAY)
MIDPOINT = int(MAX/2)
FOUND = False
while (FOUND == False):
    MIDPOINT = int(MAX/2)
    if MYVALUE > MIDPOINT:
        MIN = int(MIDPOINT)
        MAX = len(ARRAY)
    elif int(MYVALUE) < int(MIDPOINT):
        MAX = int(MIDPOINT)
        MIN = 1
    elif int(MYVALUE) == int(MIDPOINT):
        print("Value found. Value is " + int(MIDPOINT))
    else:
        print("Value not found")
```

This keeps returning the following error, and I'm sure there are other problems with it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/auroraguild/Desktop/binary search.py", line 8, in <module>
    if MYVALUE > MIDPOINT:
TypeError: unorderable types: builtin_function_or_method() > int()
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: And your binsearch looks very dirty, there is the example of nice one: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/bisect.py

Comment: You can't do a binary search on that list, because it's not in order.

Comment: PEP8 recommends all capitals for constants: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
MYVALUE = input()
```

Not:

```
MYVALUE = input
```